# Changing the entire control choices using wp.customize with JavaScript

Tags: theme-development, ajax, javascript, theme-customizer, json

Let's say I have two customizer controls "setting_category" and "setting_font", I'm trying to change the choices of "setting_font" upon changing the value of "setting_category". Here's what I'm doing:

```
( function( $ ) {
    var api = wp.customize;

    api( 'setting_category', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( to ) {
            var newChoices = {};
            // get new data from JSON using 'to' and populate the 'newChoices'

            api( 'setting_font' ).changeTheChoices( newChoices );
        } );
    } );
} )( jQuery );
```

How can it be done with JavaScript? Any trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that I found, it may be useful for some instance:

```
parent.wp.customize.control( 'setting_category', function( control ) {
    control.setting.bind( function( to ) {
        var selectElem = parent.wp.customize.control( 'setting_font' ).container.find( 'select' );

        selectElem.empty();
        $.each( jsonData['items'], function( key, item ) {
            if ( item['category'] === to ) {
                var option = $( '<option></option>' )
                        .attr( "value", encodeURIComponent( item['family'] ) )
                        .text( item['family'] );
                selectElem.append( option );
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You just need to replace `changeTheChoices()` with `set()` as this is a method on `wp.customize.Setting`. See the following which also refactors a bit:

```
wp.customize( 'setting_category', 'setting_font', function( categorySetting, fontSetting ) {
    categorySetting.bind( function( category ) {
        var newChoices = {};
        // get new data from JSON using 'category' and populate the 'newChoices'

        fontSetting.set( newChoices );
    });
});
```

Tip: I suggest not using "`setting`" in the IDs for your settings.

Comment: It's not working, please see my answer if that's also what you're intended.

Comment: I didn't realize you wanted to change the available choices rather than just change the selected choice.