# Customizer - binding jQuery created controls

Tags: theme-customizer

I tried several plugins posted by Weston Ruter for jQuery created controls for the WP Customizer. They work but are different from those created via PHP.
For example, controls created with PHP (`customizer.php`) respond normally to code in `customize-controls.js` or in `customize-previews.js`:

```js
api( 'tzkmx_test_control', function( value ){
    value.bind( function( to ) {
        var answer = to;
    });
});
```

Controls created with jQuery do not respond to binding!
Does anyone know how **to bind** them?

Comment: I do not see any jQuery controls in your question to debug, can you update your question using the `edit` link?

Comment: Did you also create the setting? Creating a controls is one thing, but binding to a value only works if you've first created the setting itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tom,

Example:

1. Just download the plugin **WPSE 286375: A dynamic dropdown-pages control** from [here](https://gist.github.com/westonruter/00c351830e0a15cef7672b748720a7ff):
2. Extract next two files in the wp plugin folder: (wp-contents/plugins)

   ```
   wpse-286375-controls.js and 
   wpse-286375.php
   ```
3. Activate  WPSE 286375 plugin
4. Go to wp dashboard/Customize/Homepage Settings

   there are 2 controls - Homepage and Posts Page
   with control's IDs **"page_on_front"** and **"page_for_posts"**

   and

   third control - Featured Page (it is from the activated plugin) with control ID
   **"special_page"**

   It is created with jQuery in wpse-286375-controls.js via:

   > ```
   > component.addControl = function() {
   > api.control.add( new api.Control( 'special_page', _.extend(
   >   {},
   >   component.defaultParams,
   >   {       type: 'dropdown-pages',
   >           section: 'static_front_page',
   >   }) ) );};
   > ```
5. Copy next code in your working project in your file customize-controls.js and debug
   it with chrome/firefox:

   > ```
   > wp.customize('page_on_front', function( value ) {
   >           // Listen to value changes.
   >                    value.bind( function( to ) {
   >                             var answer = to;
   >              });});
   > ```

   Try to change something in Homepage control and voila the **bind works** and in
   var answer we can see the page ID of Home page.
6. Now change the ID of Featured Page only:

   > ```
   >    wp.customize('special_page', function( value ) {                                
   > // Listen to value changes.                                                       
   >      value.bind( function( to ) {                                                 
   >               var answer = to;                                                     
   >    });});
   > ```

Try to change something in Featured Page control -> No bind and Nothing happen!

Comment: Aristeides, Weston did it in the plugin file wpse-286375.php.
The name of the setting is **"favorite_page".**

Answer (score 0):

Here's the **5ervant**'s [solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/266853/changing-the-entire-control-choices-using-wp-customize-with-javascript/266908#266908) that I found:

```
     parent.wp.customize.control( 'special_page', function( control ) {
             control.setting.bind( function( to ) {
                                var answer = to;
     });});
```

Thanks!